# Construct a DFA of the language L = { L1 \ L2 }

Tags: dfa, complement, demorgans-law

How can I construct a DFA of the language L = { L1 \ L2 }

The DFA's of L1 and L2 are given, but how can I "substract" one DFA from another? Is this somehow possible with the relative complement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory) and DeMorgans Law?

[image]

My solution:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, the desired DFA can be obtained by using a modified product automaton, as used for the intersection of `L1` and `L2`, but the terminal states have to be defined differently. Instead of making a product state `(q_1,q_2)` a terminal state if and only if `q_1` and `q_2` are terminal states in `A(L1)` and `A(L2)` respectively, define it to be a terminal state if and only if `q_1` is a terminal state and `q_2` is *not* a terminal state.

I'm not quite sure if besides this elementary argument, the result can be applied by the set formulation of [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I didn't get it. I added the specific exercise with my previous edit, could you try to provide a more detailed answer to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the product automaton to recognize the intersection of two regular languages?

Comment: I know how to intersect two automatons with the cartesian product (is this the same as "product automaton"?).

Comment: @jannnik To my understanding, it is. Use the same construction, but define the terminal states of the construction differently, as sketched in the answer. Consequently, the resulting automaton will be in a terminal state if and only if `A(L1)` would have reached a terminal state but `A(L2)` would *not* have reached a terminal state. This is opposed to the construction for intersection, where the resulting automaton will reach terminal state if and only if `A(L1)` *and* `A(L2)` would have reached terminal state. Does this help?

Comment: Ok I think I understand it. Is is right that the only terminal state in my example is (4i)?

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much! I added my solution. Can you please have a look at it and check if it's correct?

Comment: There seems to be a mistake, as reading `b` from `2ii` should lead to `3i`.

Comment: I corrected my solution because I missed more than the b from 2ii. Could you check it again, please?